# Retrieve a list of Events

Tags: javascript, events, resume, addeventlistener

Is there any way to retrieve a list of events of a DOM in Javascript?

e.g. I register FuncA, FuncB, FuncC  for the **onclick** event using **AddEvent** or **AddEventListener** methods.  How do I get the reference of all these functions for that **onclick** event?

Ideally, I want to have a function like this:

```
eventList = getEvents(obj, 'onclick');
```

and will get the events in an array.

Any idea?

or Any function that I can use to "PAUSE" an event and "RESUME" later?  e.g.
I want to pause  obj.click   for a while until something happens, then resume it.  I don't want to remove all the events and register them back.
I know there is event stop propagation function, but that one cannot be resumed.

Comment: Did you mean attachEvent and addEventListener?

Answer (score 3):

Create something which hooks into addEvent or addEvent listener and then track it the additions/subtractions. But I wouldn't rewrite this, as jQuery already does it.

Here's the exact same question, but with all the answers:

[How to find event listeners on a DOM node when debugging or from the JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node)

(contains three methods of doing what you want)

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, the code I'm working on is not using JQuery framework.  It is using MochiKit.  So, I'm stuck with looking for the more premitive type of solution.

Comment: You can still select an answer or drop the question? :)